# Computational Geometry (Polygons)

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

If we are given a set S of segments , Can we design an algorithm that will test if the segments in set S can form a polygon , i am not interested if they are intersecting polygons or not , i just want to know on what criteria can i test ,

any suggestions

Comment: Are you looking for polygons with vertices, which are segments endpoints *only*? Or you allow segments intersections also to become polygon vertices?

Comment: Seconding Aleksey's question. Consider segments collection that looks like the symbol "#", for example (1,0)-(1,4); (3,0)-(3,4); (0,1)-(4,1); (0,3)-(4,3). Do they form a polygon (the middle square) or not, for your purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Construct a graph data structure in which nodes represent segments in your set S. Connect segment A and segment B with an edge if A and B intersect. Do a traversal of the graph to determine if there are any cycles. Each cycle corresponds to a candidate polygon.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is a possibly more direct solution (the first answer is constructing the dual graph which may be less obvious).

Construct a graph where each (distinct) endpoint from the given segments is a vertex and each given line segment is an edge. Do a depth-first-search traversal of this graph to find cycles. These cycles are candidate polygons.